# Error loading csv file: Huge text node out of memory

Tags: php, csv, nginx, phpexcel

While loading a 38MB .csv file using PHPExcel, I am getting a `huge text node: out of memory` error even though I have set the `php memory_limit` to 1024M.

Any idea how the large .csv file can be loaded?

**Error**

`Error loading file "data.csv": Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node: out of memory in /var/www/site/data.csv, line: 264094 in /var/www/site/vendor/CodePlex/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Reader/HTML.php line 458`

**PHP Code**

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

$inputFileName = '/var/www/site/data.csv';
$phpExcel = new PHPExcel;

//  Read your Excel workbook
try 
{
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName); 
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} 
catch(Exception $e) 
{
     die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

**php.ini**

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M
```

Comment: Seems like a memory problem, what's the max allowed in php.ini?

Comment: It's already high, you can still try to get it higher and see if it works, but it will consume a lot of memory though

Comment: I set `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M')` and still get the same memory error. Is ini_set sufficient or must php.ini be changed too?

Comment: Try to change in php.ini and restart apache

Comment: @Nyxynyx Will you work with real excel files?

Comment: By the way, what's in this line? Any specific data?

Comment: @Fabio I set the memory_limit to 5120M and still get the same memory error. phpinfo() shows the updated memory_limit.

Comment: Wow this must be something else then, is there anything in that line?

Comment: @b1- It was a csv output from a software QuantumGIS, just 3 columns. Its not necessary for me to use the .csv in Excel, I am trying to import a million rows into my PostgreSQL database

Comment: @Fabio Line/row 264094 in the .csv is `-72.386142 42.511589 597498
`

Comment: I thought it was a special charcter or something causing the error, i would give `fgetcsv` a try to see if it works

Comment: If you're simply loading CSV data to import into a database (or similar) then PHPExcel is overkill - if you want to manipulate the data through PHPExcel in any way, then use cell caching or similar methods that are provided by Excel to reduce the memory requirements

Comment: However, from the error message given, you're not actually loading a CSV file, you're loading HTML markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) and load csv line by line.

```
$file = '/path/filename.csv';

$f = fopen($file, 'rb');

while( $cols = fgetcsv($f) ) 
{
  // $cols[0]; // first column of the current row
}

fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions on reading issue of high volume Excel files with PHPExcel

[How to read large worksheets from large Excel files (27MB+) with PHPExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666746/how-to-read-large-worksheets-from-large-excel-files-27mb-with-phpexcel)

One of the answers suggests reading huge file in chunks.