# How to upload to php a xlsx worksheet with 240000+ rows?

Tags: php, excel

Right now I have an error on upload a xlsx worksheet with **240000** rows.

The problem is the code can't read correctly the file. This is what i got from result of my php code.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : building attribute
in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelamysql\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 625

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex
celamysql\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 625

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Memory allocati
on failed : xmlSAX2AttributeNs in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelamysql\Classes\PHPExcel\R
eader\Excel2007.php on line 625

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): >48161</v></c><c r="B27695" s="10" t="s"><v>49
</v></c><c r="C27695" s="11" t="s" in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelamysql\Classes\PHPExc
el\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 625

Warning: simplexml_load_string():
                                 ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelamysql\Classes\PHPExc
el\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 625

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content a
t the end of the document in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelamysql\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader
\Excel2007.php on line 625

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): >48161</v></c><c r="B27695" s="10" t="s"><v>49
</v></c><c r="C27695" s="11" t="s" in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelamysql\Classes\PHPExc
el\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 625

Warning: simplexml_load_string():
                                 ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelamysql\Classes\PHPExc
el\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 625
```

And this is a piece of php code:

```
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('C:\xampp\htdocs\excelamysql\Maestra.xlsx');
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);   

foreach($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row)
{
$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(TRUE);
 foreach($cellIterator as $cell)
 {
  $val = $cell->getValue();

  $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
 }
}

for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) 
{ 
  $val=array(); 
  $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(12, $row);
  $val[] = $cell->getValue();
  $sql="insert ignore into Estado (Id_est,nom_est )values('".'auto'."','" . $val[0] . "')"; 
  $link= mysql("pago_coberturas", $sql); 
  $sql2="ALTER TABLE Estado AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
  $link2= mysql("pago_coberturas",$sql2);
```

Comment: Configure PHP in php.ini to allow more memory usage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read large worksheets from large Excel files (27MB+) with PHPExcel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666746/how-to-read-large-worksheets-from-large-excel-files-27mb-with-phpexcel)

Comment: Have you tried using SQLyog and importing the XLSX straight into the table from the local file?

Comment: Have you tried enabling PHPExcel's cell caching to reduce memory usage? Have you tried loading the file in "chunks"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with lifting the `memory_limit`, unless you want your whole sheet to end up in there two times: as a string, and as simplexml representation. PHPExcel is perfect for smaller sheets, but by default it sucks at handling large data sets (primary concern is that it's slow, secondary is that it consumes a bunch of memory as you already noticed);

You have a few options:

1. If you really really want to use PHPExcel, of course you could figure out some solution involving it, there is one available in here: [How to read large worksheets from large Excel files (27MB+) with PHPExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666746/how-to-read-large-worksheets-from-large-excel-files-27mb-with-phpexcel) - be cautious as there are a few caveats to that
2. You could save your `XLS` file as `CSV`, and use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) built-in function - it is lightning fast, and only consume as much memory, as one row can take
3. If you are stuck with `xlsx`, then hey, it's just a zip archive. You could unpack it with [ZipArchive](http://php.net/ZipArchive) class, and then read the sheet's data with [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/XMLReader)

The CSV way will be the most robust one

Answer (score 0):

As Adam said, PHPExcel is not designed to handle large worksheets. They implemented different caching strategies as well as some options to optimize the amount of memory used, but this affects the performance badly.

If you have to stick with XLSX, check out [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout). It's an open-source library that can read and write XLSX files and was optimized for scale.

Reading the 240000+ rows will take about 1-2 minutes and require less than 10MB of memory!