# How to export large mysql db table to excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm trying to export a large mysql table (~25000 rows) to excel using phpexcel. But when I run the query to pull the data from the database, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes)

I would assume I should change my `memory_limit` value but I don't know what a reasonable value for this should be and I know that something like:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

is not a good idea...

What's the best approach to this situation?

Comment: Increase memory limit. But don't set it to -1. Set it to a large enough value so errors go away.

Comment: You can try to read in the file in chunks. Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4666824/1144203).

Comment: PHPExcel is memory intensive . You can write your own code to export as a .csv file if that is okay with you .

Comment: If you need BIFF format rather than CSV format, look at the methods that PHPExcel has for reducing memory usage, such as cell caching

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for my English (I speak Spanish)
You could use `excel` for `MySQL` and do what you want

You can refer the following link

http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try phpmyadmin? I have used phpmyadmin to export a table with around 12000 records to excel sheet..