# PHPExcel unable to read More than 30k Records with 53 columns i.e 10.5MB for .xlsx files

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, xlsx

I am using Codeigniter for just reading only 1 sheet from .xlsx file and storing it into database using batch

> Error occur only if i insert more than 30k rows i.e 31k will throw error and till 30k it is absolutely fine

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

 Severity: Warning

 Message: XMLReader::XML(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer

 Message: XMLReader::XML(): Unable to load source data

 Message: XMLReader::setParserProperty(): Invalid parser property

 Message: XMLReader::read(): Load Data before trying to read

 Filename: Reader/Excel2007.php

 Line Number: 203

 Function: XML, listWorksheetInfo, setParserProperty 

 //(I combined the messages as it will be very long)
```

The Solutions i have tried is

[PHPExcel runs out of 256, 512 and also 1024MB of RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817651/phpexcel-runs-out-of-256-512-and-also-1024mb-of-ram)

[How to read large worksheets from large Excel files (27MB+) with PHPExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666746/how-to-read-large-worksheets-from-large-excel-files-27mb-with-phpexcel)

> I need to Insert minimum 65k Records with 53columns of data to the
>   database

- I have Changed the chunk Size from 20 to 1000
- I have already loaded the ChunkRead filter and excel Library and also used the Cache method and the unset method of PHPExcel but seems of no use
- I have used batch_insert in the model to insert data

  $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
  $cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '8MB');
  PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
  $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets ();
  unset ( $objPHPExcel );

MY Example Code:

```
    public function report() {
        $path = "files/test_31k_rows";
        $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
        $inputFileName = $path;
        //Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType 
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader ( $inputFileType );
        // Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk" 
        $chunkSize = 100;
        //Create a new Instance of our Read Filter 
        $chunkFilter = new ReadFilter ();
        // Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter that we've Instantiated 
        $objReader->setReadFilter ( $chunkFilter );
        // Loop to read our worksheet in "chunk size" blocks $startRow is set to 2 initially because we always read the headings in row #1
        $startRow = 2;
        $chunkFilter->setRows ( $startRow, $chunkSize );
        $worksheetData = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($inputFileName);
        foreach ($worksheetData as $worksheet) {
            $highestRow=$worksheet['totalRows']; 
        }
        for($startRow = 2; $startRow <= $highestRow; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
            $batch = array();
            //Tell the Read Filter, the limits on which rows we want to read this iteration 
            $chunkFilter->setRows ( $startRow, $chunkSize );
            // Load only the rows that match our filter from $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object 
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load ( $inputFileName );
            foreach ( $objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator () as $worksheet ) {
                $worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle ();
                $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow (); // e.g. 10
                $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn (); // e.g 'F'
                $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString ( $highestColumn );
                $nrColumns = ord ( $highestColumn ) - 64;
                $loopForRows = ($highestRow > $chunkSize) ? ($startRow + $chunkSize) : ($highestRow + 1);
                for($row = $startRow; $row < $loopForRows; ++ $row) {
                    $val = array ();
                    for($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
                        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow ( $col, $row );           
                        if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
                            $InvDate= $cell->getValue();
                            $InvDate = date($format = "Y-m-d H:i:s", PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($InvDate));
                            $val [] = $InvDate;
                        } else {
                            if($col == 52) {
                                $val [] = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getFormattedValue($cell->getValue());
                            } else {
                                $val [] = $cell->getValue ();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $data = array (
                            "val0" => $val [0],
                            "val1" => $val [1],
                            "val2" => $val [2],
                            "val3" => $val [3],
                            "val4" => $val [4],
                            "val5" => $val [5],
                            "val6" => $val [6],
                            "val7" => $val [7],
                            "val8" => $val [8],
                            "val9" => $val [9],
                            "val11" => $val [10],
                            "val11" => $val [11],
                            "val12" => $val [12],
                            "val13" => $val [13],
                            "val14" => $val [14],
                            "val15" => $val [15],
                            "val16" => $val [16],
                            "val17" => $val [17],
                            "val18" => $val [18],
                            "val19" => $val [19],
                            "val20" => $val [20],
                            "val21" => $val [21],
                            "val22" => $val [22],
                            "val23" => $val [23],
                            "val24" => $val [24],
                            "val25" => $val [25],
                            "val26" => $val [26],
                            "val27" => $val [27],
                            "val28" => $val [28],
                            "val29" => $val [29],
                            "val30" => $val [30],
                            "val31" => $val [31],
                            "val32" => $val [32],
                            "val33" => $val [33],
                            "day_1" => $val [34],
                            "day_2" => $val [35],
                            "day_3" => $val [36],
                            "day_4" => $val [37],
                            "day_5" => $val [38],
                            "day_6" => $val [39],
                            "day_7" => $val [40],
                            "day_8" => $val [41],
                            "day_9" => $val [42],
                            "day_10" => $val [43],
                            "day_11" => $val [44],
                            "day_12" => $val [45],
                            "day_13" => $val [46],
                            "day_14" => $val [47],
                            "day_15" => $val [48],
                            "val49" => $val [49],
                            "val50" => $val [50],
                            "val51" => $val [51],
                            "val52" => $val [52] 
                    );
                    $batch[] = $data;   
                } 
            } 
                //$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets ();
                //unset ( $objPHPExcel );
        $this->Upload_model->upload_insert($batch);
        } 
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the php config file (in IIS) there's variables call post_max_size and memory_limit. I've had to alter these in the past. It may be different if you're using Apache

Comment: I have used memory_limit=-1 and max_execution =0 for testing purpose but no result