# Search and fetch record from xlsx file in php

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I have an **Excel** file with `.xlsx` extension containing record of about **150000** (17 MB).

Excel file is having (`name`, `place`, `pincode`) columns. I want to search file with `pincode` and retrieve a that specific row which matches my `pincode`.

I have tried different `PHPExcel` reader but as I have search **150000** records the entire script hangs with no results.

**It works with small files**. Is there any solution to make the search and retrieval of records faster.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at:

[Reading large worksheets with PHPExcel...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666746/how-to-read-large-worksheets-from-large-excel-files-27mb-with-phpexcel)

They also link to a potentially faster reader (I have not tested this):

[Faster XLSX Reader](https://github.com/akeneo-labs/spreadsheet-parser)