# How do you process large Excel files with phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

When I try to read a large Excel file (106k rows, 24MB) my php script stops without any errors or warnings. I have drilled down to find out it halts at this specific statement:

```
$obj = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
```

The manual shows no memory limitations so I don’t know how to fix this. Script works fine with smaller files but it’s clumsy having to break files into smaller ones just to process thru the script.

Appreciate any solutions/ pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read large worksheets from large Excel files (27MB+) with PHPExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666746/how-to-read-large-worksheets-from-large-excel-files-27mb-with-phpexcel)

Comment: Yeah, it seems you must be running into a memory limit. The limit is somehere around 128 MB, but you can increase it. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/increase-memory-limit However you must first check the error log to make sure this is the problem.

Comment: But how am I running into 128MB limit with a 24MB file?